# values in dataframe to zero if in interval

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

I am still new to R and I was trying to put values in my dataframe to zero, if they are in the interval IR e {-0,5: 0,5} 
The data frame looks like this:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1 -0.2  1.0  0.7
2  0.2 -0.5 -0.2
3  1.0  0.2  3.0
4  0.5  2.0  4.0
5 -0.7  4.0  0.3
```

I found easy solutions only for one way (e.g. < 0.5):

```
dat[< 0.5] <- 0
```

but dat[ >-0.5 & <0.5] <- 0 doesn't work.

I found a solution, but this one is not very elegant:

```
var1 <- c(-0.2,0.2,1,0.5,-0.7)
var2 <- c(1,-0.5,0.2,2,4)
var3 <- c(0.7,-0.2,3,4,0.3)
dat <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
Rows <- length(dat[,1])
Cols <- length(dat[1,])
for (i in 1:Rows) {
  for (j in 1:Cols)
  if (dat[i,j] < 0.5 & dat[i,j] > -0.5){dat[i,j] = 0}
}
```

This results in the data frame:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1  0.0  1.0  0.7
2  0.0 -0.5  0.0
3  1.0  0.0  3.0
4  0.5  2.0  4.0
5 -0.7  4.0  0.0
```

Could you help me to find a more elegant solution for this problem?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `dat[dat>-0.5&dat<0.5]<-0`

Comment: ahh, i forgot the dat inside. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
> dat[ abs(dat) < 0.5] <- 0
> dat
  var1 var2 var3
1  0.0  1.0  0.7
2  0.0 -0.5  0.0
3  1.0  0.0  3.0
4  0.5  2.0  4.0
5 -0.7  4.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of creating the data frame with a for loop, you can use ``data.frame``:
var1 <- c(-0.2,0.2,1,0.5,-0.7)
var2 <- c(1,-0.5,0.2,2,4)
var3 <- c(0.7,-0.2,3,4,0.3)

dat<-data.frame(var1=var1,var2=var2,var3=var3)

To replace values based on your conjunction do:
dat[dat>-0.5 & dat<0.5]=0
```

You can also take a look at `tidyverse` or `dplyr` package which make easier the data processing.